# Integrating a joint distribution over only one variable -- a conditional moment?

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the meaning of an integral like
$$ \int dx_1 x_1 P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$
for a joint probability distribution $P$?
Can this be interpreted as the first moment of $x_1$ held conditional on the other $x_2, \dots, x_n$?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: @herbsteinberg what I find confusing about this is that if $\int v W(x,v) dv = \langle v \rangle P(x)$, where $W(x,v)$ is the joint distribution and $P(x)$ is a reduced distribution,  then how do joint moments come out? Is $\langle xv \rangle = \int x \langle v \rangle P(x,t) dx$?

Comment: What do you mean by (v)P(x)?  Last statement has a parameter t.  Typo?

Comment: $\langle v \rangle$ is the "expectation of $v$ conditional on $x$" as in the original question: $\langle v \rangle  P(x) = \int dv W(x,v).$ Maybe this would be better written as $\langle v|x \rangle$? The last statement should be $\langle x v \rangle = \int x \langle v \rangle P(x) dx$.

Comment: Sorry for the searchy questions. Largely I'm confused by the meaning of $\bar{v}$ used here: https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.93.1169

Comment: Confusing notation:  $(xv)=\int x(v)P(x)dx$.  $x$ is dummy in RHS.  What is meaning of $(xv)$?

Comment: $\langle x v \rangle$ is the joint moment of $x$ and $v$ over the distribution $W(x,v)$. $P(x)$ is the reduced distribution $\int W(x,v) dv = P(x)$

Comment: Joint moment?  Product, sum, two-d?  Use different letters for dummy than argument for expression.